# BS4 get the full CSS selector for an element in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am writing a web scraper using python where I want am getting some element using BS4. I want to get the full CSS selector link of the element

```
page_r = requests.get(page_url)
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_r.content, 'html.parser')
elements = page_soup.find('body').find_all()
for element in elements:
    print("CSS selector for this element")
    # here I want to print full CCS selector like body>section>div:nth-of-type(3)>p:nth-of-type(4)
```

How do I get that using BS4 or a function that can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code to print CSS selectors of page elements:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def nth_of_type(elem):
    count, curr = 0, 0
    for i, e in enumerate(elem.find_parent().find_all(recursive=False), 1):
        if e.name == elem.name:
            count += 1
        if e == elem:
            curr = i
    return '' if count == 1 else ':nth-of-type({})'.format(curr)

def get_css_selector(elem):
    rv = [elem.name + nth_of_type(elem)]
    while True:
        elem = elem.find_parent()
        if not elem or elem.name == '[document]':
            return ' > '.join(rv[::-1])
        rv.append(elem.name + nth_of_type(elem))


sample_html = '''
<html>
    <body>
        <div>Hello</div>
        <div>World</div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
'''

page_soup = BeautifulSoup(sample_html, 'html.parser')
elements = page_soup.find('body').find_all()
for element in elements:
    css_selector = get_css_selector(element)
    txt = page_soup.select_one(css_selector)
    print(css_selector)
    print(txt)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Print:

```
html > body > div:nth-of-type(1)
<div>Hello</div>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
html > body > div:nth-of-type(2)
<div>World</div>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
html > body > div:nth-of-type(3)
<div>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
</div>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
html > body > div:nth-of-type(3) > ul
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
html > body > div:nth-of-type(3) > ul > li:nth-of-type(1)
<li>1</li>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
html > body > div:nth-of-type(3) > ul > li:nth-of-type(2)
<li>2</li>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
html > body > div:nth-of-type(3) > ul > li:nth-of-type(3)
<li>3</li>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```